# Why does React.js axios data show in console but not on the screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm making a React Axios Project with https://swapi.dev/api/films/, the characters data shows another API link so I make an Axios loop to show characters name. The characters name can show in console, so it should be success but the name is not showing on the screen. Already return the data but still not showing.

This is the web app picture:

[image]

This is the full code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";


class MovieDetail extends Component {
  state = {
    showMovieDetail: false,
  };

  movieListClicked = () => {
    this.setState({ showMovieDetail: !this.state.showMovieDetail });
  };

  getCharactersDetails = () => {
    const charsAPILink = this.props.characters;

    const charData = return charsAPILink.map((data) => {
      axios.get(data).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data.name);
        return response.data.name;
      });
    });

    return charData;

  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="MovieDetail" onClick={this.movieListClicked}>
        {!this.state.showMovieDetail ? (
          <h2>{this.props.title}</h2>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <h3>
              Title : {this.props.title} <br />
              Episode : {this.props.episode} <br />
              {this.props.opening} <br />
              Director : {this.props.director} <br />
              Producer : {this.props.producer} <br />
              Date : {this.props.date} <br />
              Characters : {this.getCharactersDetails()}
            </h3>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MovieDetail;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to write the async data in render function and hence it is not going to show.

You can save data in state and update the state.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";


class MovieDetail extends Component {
  state = {
    showMovieDetail: false,
    charData: []
  };

  movieListClicked = () => {
    this.setState({ showMovieDetail: !this.state.showMovieDetail });
  };

 componentDidMount() {
   this.getCharactersDetails()
}

  getCharactersDetails = () => {
    const charsAPILink = this.props.characters;
    const temp = []
    
    charsAPILink.map((data) => {
      temp.push(axios.get(data))
    });
    
  promise.all(temp)
   .then(res => res)
    .then(responses => promise.all(responses.map(r => r.json()))
      .then(data => this.setState({charData: data}))
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="MovieDetail" onClick={this.movieListClicked}>
        {!this.state.showMovieDetail ? (
          <h2>{this.props.title}</h2>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <h3>
              Title : {this.props.title} <br />
              Episode : {this.props.episode} <br />
              {this.props.opening} <br />
              Director : {this.props.director} <br />
              Producer : {this.props.producer} <br />
              Date : {this.props.date} <br />
              Characters : {charData.map(item => {
                 return (<span> { item.name } </span>)
              }}
            </h3>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MovieDetail;
```

Comment: hi thanks for the response, but there's a little error on your code on the promise section https://imgur.com/a/Fp23CPt I don't know how to fix it

Comment: sorry for late reply, it seems there is 2 more error here https://imgur.com/a/e6h82E2

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning the axios response to map function, and also better to use async await to wait till the api response and then return. Try this :-

getCharactersDetails = async () => {
const charsAPILink = this.props.characters;

```
const charData = await getChars(charsAPILink )
return charData
```

};

```
async function getChars(charsAPILink) {
  let allChars = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < charsAPILink.length; i++) {
    await axios.get(charsAPILink[i]).then((response) => {
      allChars.push(response.data.title);
    });
  }
  return allChars;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, tried your method but now the screen not showing anything and it shows this error https://imgur.com/a/JxwjLBR but the name still shown in console tho